# Why ScheduledExecutorService cannot be shutted down from the Runnable command itself?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to schedule a command which will be executed in every 1 second. The command will increment a counter and when the counter would reach certain limit, the execution will be stopped and the ExecutorService will shut down. So I have written following code snippet:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SchedulerTest {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask;

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public SchedulerTest() {

    }

    private void check() {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int currentValue = counter.incrementAndGet();                   
                System.out.println(currentValue);

                if(currentValue == 5) {
                    scheduledTask.cancel(false);

                    scheduler.shutdown();
                    while(!scheduler.isTerminated()) {}
                }
            }
        };

        scheduledTask = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SchedulerTest().check();
    }
}
```

The above code is solely for demonstrating purpose.

Now I can see following in my Eclipse console:

[image: console image]

The red button on the top right, shows that the JVM is still running as the ExecutorService is running. I have placed log inside the `while` and I have seen the loop is never terminated.

I would like to know what is the reason behind this behaviour? Is there any way to terminate the ExecutorService from the Runnable command itself?

I am using JDK6.

Comment: `while(!scheduler.isTerminated()) {}` get rid of this line ... Spoiler: It keeps the thread running which keeps the scheduler from terminating which keeps the condition false ...

Comment: `System.exit(-1);`   ...

Comment: It's interesting, I executed the code and found that the thread terminated after removing the while loop. `isShutdown` can also work fine.

Comment: @Fildor, I also have logged the status of `scheduler.isTerminated()` immediately after the `scheduler.shutdown();` and it returns `false`. So which makes the program execution to enter the `while` and since the `run` method is not finished, thus the thread which is running the `Runnable` get blocked by the infinite `while`.

Comment: Exactly. You have to let the thread "die" - i.e. exit the `run()` method. Only then `isTerminated` will become `true`.

Comment: @Fildor, could you please convert our discussions into an answer so that I can accept it and let world find the answer of such problems in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the run method you check for termination status of the threadpool:

```
while(!scheduler.isTerminated()) {}
```

This will do the following:

- The thread executing that runnable will enter the loop.
- Since the thread is still "active" i.e. has not finished `run` the condition will be true ( "not terminated = true" ).
- That will keep the thread in the loop **forever**.

So delete that "while" and the threadpool will be terminated as expected.

P.S.: If you want to wait on the main execution line for the pool to be terminated you can use [awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).